# Access commandline arguments to WPF application in separate appdomain

Tags: c#, wpf, command-line-arguments, appdomain

Is there a clean way to access the commandline arguments passed as part of an AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly call that starts a WPF application?

I'm spinning up a WPF application in a separate app domain and passing arguments to the application like so:

```
AppDomain moduleDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Friendly Name");
moduleDomain.ExecuteAssembly(path, new[] { "arg1", "arg2" });
```

There's a [work-around](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/680671e1-c79c-486f-8c0a-e998589bf8cc) to access these arguments, since both [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx) and [StartupEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup.aspx) return the commandline arguments for the original application, not the one spun up with ExecuteAssembly().

I would like to access the arguments passed to the WPF application without having to manually define a Main method, preferably using StartupEventArgs. Is there a way to do so?

Starting the WPF application in a separate process works, but has performance penalties and complicates debugging.

Comment: Considering that command line arguments is just a `string` and they are immutable, why not just hold it inside some `string` property and pass the value of that property. You can pass strings between different domains ? I think, yes.

Comment: Thanks, Tigran, this lead me to a solution that I'm happy with, using AppDomain.SetData. The system won't let me post an answer for another 8 hours, but I'll post the full solution as soon as possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tigran's comment lead me to a solution that I'm happy with, using [AppDomain.SetData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37z40s1c.aspx) instead of using command line arguments. The basic outline looks like this:

```
AppDomain moduleDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Friendly Name");
moduleDomain.SetData("arg1", "arg1Value");
moduleDomain.SetData("arg2", "arg2Value");
moduleDomain.ExecuteAssembly(path);
```

Then, to access the 'arguments' in the WPF app:

```
string arg1Value = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("arg1");
string arg2Value = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("arg2");
```

This works well for my use case.